# How can i make an automaticly retry after post request fails

Tags: python, session, proxy, python-requests

I need to code that Python retry after failed connection to website, like when i try to post a request & its fails that python **automaticly retrys**. I use post requests and when python fails to send the request the code will stop but i need that its retry!

I hope someone can help me
Thanks

Comment: Can you put a sample of the code you want to retry ?

Comment: yes sure:

session.post(cart, data=payload, proxies=proxy)

and sometimes its fail to connect & then i want to retry it

Comment: Could you add it into your question using a code block so it’s easier for people to see

Comment: its just a normal post request, and when the connection fails i want to retry it :)

Comment: Use try, except

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this,

```
while True:
    try:
         session.post(cart, data=payload, proxies=proxy)
         break
    except:
         continue
```

The main loop is a while True loop, it will continue forever unless it successfully completes the try statement. As long as there is an exception, it will go back to the top of the while loop.

Comment: Note, while this would work, there's a number of things that could be improved here. Namely, 1) you should definitely log the exception 2) You should perhaps narrow the caught exception to something like `HttpError`, and 3) you should probably give up at some point, at least depending on your usecase.